# PHP Forming Custom Array from Array within array

Tags: php, morris.js

I'm having an array of three months which has **Three Months Data** and it holds **Savings & Discount Information** something like the below:

**graphData** holds the **DataArr**.

[DataArr] => Array

```
    [0] => Array
            (
             [data] => Array
                 (
                   [0] => Array 
                      ( 
                        [Month] => 10 Jan 2019
                        [Cost] => 60.3
                        [Name] => Savings
                      )
                   [1] => Array 
                      ( 
                        [Month] => 10 Feb 2019
                        [Cost] => 45.3
                        [Name] => Savings
                      )
                   [2] => Array 
                      ( 
                        [Month] => 10 Mar 2019
                        [Cost] => 50.6
                        [Name] => Savings
                      )
                )
           )
    [1] => Array
            (
             [data] => Array
                 (
                   [0] => Array 
                      ( 
                        [Month] => 10 Jan 2019
                        [Cost] => 89.62
                        [Name] => Discount
                      )
                   [1] => Array 
                      ( 
                        [Month] => 10 Feb 2019
                        [Cost] => 20.2
                        [Name] => Discount
                      )
                   [2] => Array 
                      ( 
                        [Month] => 10 Mar 2019
                        [Cost] => 0.0
                        [Name] => Discount
                      )
                )
           )
```

**REQUIRED ARRAY - To Pass into Morris.js Line Chart**

Now I want to iterate into this array and want to have the array format in a way as below

```
           [data] => Array
                 (
                   [0] => Array 
                      ( 
                        [Month] => 10 Jan 2019
                        [Savings] => 60.3
                        [Discount] => 89.62

                      )
                   [1] => Array 
                      ( 
                        [Month] => 10 Feb 2019
                        [Saving] => 45.3
                        [Discount] => 20.2
                      )
                   [2] => Array 
                      ( 
                        [Month] => 10 Mar 2019
                        [Saving] => 50.6
                        [Discount] => 0.0
                      )
                )
```

Can you please share me how I can go about getting this into the required array using PHP? I tried array_push and other methods with JQuery Array methods as well, but all my efforts failed, and I'm working on this from past 3 days, any help is greatly appreciated.

Even tried with PHP **foreach** but even that failed, missing something and have no more ideas on how to get this working! Please let me know if any of you have much ideas on this.

Thanks

EDIT

**SAMPLE CODE I TRIED IN PHP **

```
for($k = 0; $k < sizeof($graphData['DataArr']); $k++ ) {
                for($l = 0; $l < sizeof($graphData['DataArr'][$k]); $l++ ) {
                    array_push($graphData['DataArr'], array(
                        'label' => $graphData['DataArr'][$k][$l]['label'], 
                        'percent' => $graphData['DataArr'][$k][$l]['percentage']
                            )
                    );
                }
            }
```

Here label => COST, DISCOUNT and Percentage is the value associated with the labels.

Comment: What did you try, please post code so people can help in fix the issue.

Comment: Hi Mamoun, added the sample code to the question, thanks for the reply :)

Comment: Will check it soon!

Comment: @RaviChandra Can you var_export your array and show instead of print_r()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$graphData =
    array(
        'DataArr' => 
        array
            (
            array(
             'data' => array
                 (
                   array 
                      ( 
                        'Month' => '10 Jan 2019',
                        'Cost' => 60.3,
                        'Name' => 'Savings'
                      ),
                   array 
                      ( 
                        'Month' => '10 Feb 2019',
                        'Cost' => 45.3,
                        'Name' => 'Savings'
                      ),
                   array 
                      ( 
                        'Month' => '10 Mar 2019',
                        'Cost' => 50.6,
                        'Name' => 'Savings'
                      )
                )
            ),
            array
            (
             'data' => array
                 (
                   array 
                      ( 
                        'Month' => '10 Jan 2019',
                        'Cost' => 89.62,
                        'Name' => 'Discount'
                      ),
                   array 
                      ( 
                        'Month' => '10 Feb 2019',
                        'Cost' => 20.2,
                        'Name' => 'Discount'
                      ),
                   array 
                      ( 
                        'Month' => '10 Mar 2019',
                        'Cost' => 0.0,
                        'Name' => 'Discount'
                    )
                )
           )
    )
);


$result = [];

foreach($graphData['DataArr'] as $value){
    foreach($value['data'] as $details){
        if(!isset($result['data'][$details['Month']])) $result['data'][$details['Month']]  = ['Month' => $details['Month']];
        $result['data'][$details['Month']][$details['Name']] = $details['Cost'];
    }
}

$result['data'] = array_values($result['data']); // to eliminate keys
print_r($result);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/QMVuR

- We first create a `$result` array with `data` key in it.
- We loop over `$graphData` and store the values of `Month`,`Savings` and `Discount` under the indexed key value of `Month`.
- In the end, we do [`array_values()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to remove the keys.

Comment: Thanks a bunch will see how it goes :)

Comment: @RaviChandra I hope my initial input data is in correct format(hence I asked for a var_export() in the comments).

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you provided here is the code need to produce the new Array:

```
<?php
$data = [
  [
    'data' => [
      [
        'Month' => '10 Jan 2019',
        'Cost' => 60.3,
        'Name' => 'Savings'
      ],
      [
        'Month' => '10 Feb 2019',
        'Cost' => 45.3,
        'Name' => 'Savings'
      ],
      [
        'Month' => '10 Mar 2019',
        'Cost' => 50.6,
        'Name' => 'Savings'
      ]
    ],
  ],
  [
    'data' => [
      [
        'Month' => '10 Jan 2019',
        'Cost' => 89.62,
        'Name' => 'Discount'
      ],
      [
        'Month' => '10 Feb 2019',
        'Cost' => 20.2,
        'Name' => 'Discount'
      ],
      [
        'Month' => '10 Mar 2019',
        'Cost' => 0.0,
        'Name' => 'Discount'
      ]
    ],
  ]
];

$new_arr = ['data' => []];
echo "<pre>";

foreach( $data[0]['data'] as $key => $value) {
  // $new_arr['data'][$k]['Month'] = 
  $new_arr['data'][$key]['Month'] =  $value['Month'];
  $new_arr['data'][$key]['Discount'] =  $value['Cost'];
  $new_arr['data'][$key]['Savings'] =  $data[1]['data'][$key]['Cost'];
}

print_r($new_arr);
```

**Note**: this code assumes that `$data` array will only have 2 main elements, more elements in this array might might cause different behaviour.